# Is there an order to create lombok's @Setter and @Builder?

Tags: java, lombok, mapstruct

I have a question about Lombok & MapStruct combination.

First, the class is as follows.

Person.java

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Person {
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public void setCustomName(String name) {
        this.name = "custom = " + name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String getCustomName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public static class PersonBuilder {
        public PersonBuilder customName(String name) {
            return this.customName(name);
        }
    }
}
```

PersonMapper.java

```
@Mapper
public interface PersonMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "customName", source = "personName")
    @Mapping(target = "name", ignore = true)
    Person toEntity(PersonRequest req);
}
```

I'm find that @Mapper generating code depends on dependencies order (Lombok, MapStruct)

If i use Lombok first and MapStruct second, 'XXMapperImpl.java' use setter method.
but use in reversed order, 'XXMapperImpl.java' use builder method.

```
// dependencies order: Lombok's next MapStruct
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2021-01-25T18:59:21+0900",
    comments = "version: 1.3.1.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 14.0.2 (AdoptOpenJDK)"
)
public class PersonMapperImpl implements PersonMapper {

    @Override
    public Person toEntity(PersonRequest req) {
        if ( req == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Person person = new Person();

        person.setCustomName( req.getPersonName() );

        return person;
    }
}
```

but reversed order

```
// dependencies order: Lombok's next MapStruct
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2021-01-25T18:59:21+0900",
    comments = "version: 1.3.1.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 14.0.2 (AdoptOpenJDK)"
)
public class PersonMapperImpl implements PersonMapper {

    @Override
    public Person toEntity(PersonRequest req) {
        if ( req == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        PersonBuilder person = Person.builder();

        person.customName( req.getPersonName() );

        return person.build();
    }
}
```

So, I decided to guess like this about Annotation Processor(AP)'s process.
[Reference link](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/510#issuecomment-158933941)

this case is first Lombok, second MapStruct.

1. Lombok make getter/setter method with @Data
2. MapStruct can use access method. So, make mapper code by 'setter'

---------- Next round in AP---------

3. Lombok make builder method with @Builder
4. MapStruct don't be changed. Because, code already generated.
   -> Finally, 'XXMapperImpl.java' use 'setter' method.

Next case is first MapStruct, second Lombok.

1. MapStruct try to generate, but there is nothing access method in Object class.
2. Lombok make getter/setter method with @Data.

---------- Next round in AP---------

3. Lombok make builder method with @Builder.
4. MapStruct pick up changes created by Lombok. So, MapStruct generate code by using builder.
   -> Finally, 'XXMapperImpl.java' use 'builder' method.

Question)

1. Did I understand correctly?
2. Is Lombok getter/setter and builder creation divided into two rounds? First is getter/setter and next builder?

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://mapstruct.org/faq/#Can-I-use-MapStruct-together-with-Project-Lombok

Comment: Yes, but I have never seen this article. Thank you.
Then, why are the results different by dependencies order?